# ahaving issue while creating using csvwriter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria

```
public void getPersons() 
{
Session s  = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Person.class);
c.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("id"));
List<Person> al = c.list();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();   
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer, ',', '\'');
for (Person person : al) {
System.out.println(person.getName()+"------------------"+al);    
csvWriter.writeAll(person);            // this also not work
}
```

method to read data and in csv  .what should i use here?by using csvWriter.writeAll() want to create ',' seprated file
The method writeAll(List) in the type CSVWriter is not applicable for the arguments (Person)

Answer (score 0):

Unless Person is a list of string arrays, this won't work.

You need a source for the CSVWriter (a List or Iterable of String[]s), which you can create from your list of Persons:

```
List<String[]> employees = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (Person person : al) {
    employees.add(new String[] {person.getEmployeeId(), person.getName(), person.getEtc.()})
}
```

However you produce it, you can pass this to writeAll:

```
csvWriter.writeAll(employees);
```

...and close the writer:

```
csvWriter.close();
```